# Работа метода в синхронном виде в Netty

Tags: java, сокет

У меня есть простой клиент, написанный на Netty. Я должен на сервер в первую очередь отправить данные пользователя и его пароль. Если получу положительный ответ, то продолжить работу клиента. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы метод Login работал в синхронном виде и ждал ответ от сервера?

Код клиента выглядит так:

```
Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(workerGroup)
    .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    .handler(new TRSClientInterfaceInitializer());

Channel ch = bootstrap.connect(host, port).sync().channel();
ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;

lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush("username-password" + "\n");

ch.closeFuture().sync();

if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
    lastWriteFuture.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Netty - NIO. Его суть в асинхронности. Если вам нужно выполнять всё синхронно, не используйте Netty.
2. Блочить поток таким образом - плохо.

Если уж хотите что-то такое сделать, то в хендлере клиента вызывайте свой колбек, который выполняет какие-то действия после атворизации.